# How to load external modules from node

Tags: node.js, typescript, requirejs

I'm a bit stuck without really knowing what to do next, being searching for an answer without really find any working solution after all attempts I've tried...

I've made a very simple project to demonstrate my current issue, [you can see it on github](https://github.com/balexandre/ts-stackoverflow-question) or even downloaded and run it on your machine.

[image]

This final idea is to have a `/dist/clients.js` file with the project itself, so I can use it in an HTML file (`/dist/index.html`) and as I can't use `CommonJs` as my typescript load module (I have several files and not only one) I've chosen `amd` loader (hence the requirejs call in the HTML file).

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>TS Testing...</h1>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.3/require.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="client.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require(['clients/client'],
                function(require) {
                    var sc = new require();
                }
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

typescript runs fine from `grunt ts` and creates the `client.js` with mapping

[image]

**The problem I have** is that it does not load the entire project, throwing an error:

[image]

that comes from the file `/libs/core/tc-cookies.ts`:

```
var JsCookie: Cookies.CookiesStatic = require("js-cookie");
```

**How can I load** the npm module in a way that I can use my project correctly? I have `moduleResolution: "node"` in the ts-loader options, but does not seem to do the right job...

---

### [Github project available](https://github.com/balexandre/ts-stackoverflow-question) for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the order of loading the context in not known in the current state of your project, you can write some code to provide a proper order of module loading or use some sort of module loader, like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/).
What I strongly suggest is to choose webpack and [ts-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader) which is common one choice for typescript module loading.

**Steps to get rid of that error:**

1. Change your `tsconfig.json`, it should look like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "rootDir": "."
    },
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

2. Delete all script tags in your html.
3. Create `webpack.config.js` file. See example of how `webpack.config.js` should look like on `ts-loader` npm's page. (section configuration)
4. Create script tag in your html with a path of webpack's output.